# How to get device (AOSP) Build Number in Android devices programmatically?

Tags: android, version-numbering

From within an Android Application, how can the hosting device's Build Number, as displayed in **System Settings -> About Tablet -> Build Number** be obtained programmatically for use within a Java Android application?

[image: System Settings version number on tablet]

Currently, I'm using "android.os.Build".

Comment: Why guys going to down votes on this question ? tell me reason..

Comment: this is not a duplicate question.build/version is different.

Comment: @payeli it is not duplicate.. Amit kumar. I am agree with you

Comment: yes @CapDroid please help.

Comment: @payeli I checked all question.. But he not got perfect answer which he want.. don't go for question title.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check this code:

In `Build.FINGERPRINT` you'll get the `Build Number` of the device.

> ```
> String mString = "";
>
>   mString.concat("VERSION.RELEASE {" + Build.VERSION.RELEASE + "}");
>   mString.concat("\nVERSION.INCREMENTAL {" + Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL + "}");
>   mString.concat("\nVERSION.SDK {" + Build.VERSION.SDK + "}");
>   mString.concat("\nBOARD {" + Build.BOARD + "}");
>   mString.concat("\nBRAND {" + Build.BRAND + "}");
>   mString.concat("\nDEVICE {" + Build.DEVICE + "}");
>   mString.concat("\nFINGERPRINT {" + Build.FINGERPRINT + "}");
>   mString.concat("\nHOST {" + Build.HOST + "}");
>   mString.concat("\nID {" + Build.ID + "}");
>
>   ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(mString);
> ```

**My Device Build Number :**

[image: My Device Build Number]

**`FINGERPRINT` return by the above code**

[image]

Comment: mString = mString.concat("VERSION.RELEASE {" + Build.VERSION.RELEASE + "}"); [...]

Comment: I am trying to get the build number too, and the value shown in settings doesn't match at all with Build.FINGERPRINT

Comment: @takluiper in which OS version you are checking ?

Comment: @SilentKiller I tested with two different devices, in one of them the value was correct, but in another one the value didn't match at all. Android version of the last one was 4.4

Answer (score 9):

I used `String Build_Number = Build.DISPLAY;` to get Build number as it shown at Phone settings

Answer (score 6):

To get only the Build Number value as shown on the "About Device" in settings, we can use the following static method:

```
/**
 * This method returns Build Number of the device from the OS Build fingerprint
 * @return osBuildNumber - human entered name of the device
 */
public static String getOSBuildNumber() {
    String osBuildNumber = Build.FINGERPRINT;  //"google/shamu/shamu:5.1.1/LMY48Y/2364368:user/release-keys”
    final String forwardSlash = "/";
    String osReleaseVersion = Build.VERSION.RELEASE + forwardSlash;
    try {
        osBuildNumber = osBuildNumber.substring(osBuildNumber.indexOf(osReleaseVersion));  //"5.1.1/LMY48Y/2364368:user/release-keys”
        osBuildNumber = osBuildNumber.replace(osReleaseVersion, "");  //"LMY48Y/2364368:user/release-keys”
        osBuildNumber = osBuildNumber.substring(0, osBuildNumber.indexOf(forwardSlash)); //"LMY48Y"
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("getOSBuildNumber", "Exception while parsing - " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return osBuildNumber;
}
```

This will just return the exact value of the build number. Please keep in mind that Android SDK refrains from doing this. Check the following snippet in BUILD class:

```
/** A string that uniquely identifies this build.  Do not attempt to parse this value. */
public static final String FINGERPRINT = deriveFingerprint();

/**
 * Some devices split the fingerprint components between multiple
 * partitions, so we might derive the fingerprint at runtime.
 */
private static String deriveFingerprint() {
    String finger = SystemProperties.get("ro.build.fingerprint");
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(finger)) {
        finger = getString("ro.product.brand") + '/' +
                getString("ro.product.name") + '/' +
                getString("ro.product.device") + ':' +
                getString("ro.build.version.release") + '/' +
                getString("ro.build.id") + '/' +
                getString("ro.build.version.incremental") + ':' +
                getString("ro.build.type") + '/' +
                getString("ro.build.tags");
    }
    return finger;
}
```

The above method is just reverse engineering the data provided in the "deriveFingerprint()" method.

Answer (score 5):

To get this value,  use [Build.DISPLAY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#DISPLAY). Here is an example from Verizon Note 2 ( SCH-I605 on android 4.4.2) : *KOT49H.I605VRUFND7*

Requires : API 3 or higher.

Answer (score 3):

I hope it is return same value which you want..

```
String build_number = Build.FINGERPRINT;
System.out.println("Build Number" + build_number);
```

Comment: Build.FINGERPRINT does not return build number

Comment: I am getting .. in which device you testing ?

Answer (score 2):

Use Build.DISPLAY for Build Number

Answer (score 0):

```
Log.i("TAG", "SERIAL: " + Build.SERIAL);
Log.i("TAG","MODEL: " + Build.MODEL);
Log.i("TAG","ID: " + Build.ID);
Log.i("TAG","Manufacture: " + Build.MANUFACTURER);
Log.i("TAG","brand: " + Build.BRAND);
Log.i("TAG","type: " + Build.TYPE);
Log.i("TAG","user: " + Build.USER);
Log.i("TAG","BASE: " + Build.VERSION_CODES.BASE);
Log.i("TAG","INCREMENTAL " + Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL);
Log.i("TAG","SDK  " + Build.VERSION.SDK);
Log.i("TAG","BOARD: " + Build.BOARD);
Log.i("TAG","BRAND " + Build.BRAND);
Log.i("TAG","HOST " + Build.HOST);
Log.i("TAG","FINGERPRINT: "+Build.FINGERPRINT);
Log.i("TAG","Version Code: " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
```

Ho it will work.

Comment: what are you trying to infer?