# How to get Custom SW version number of android

Tags: android, android-version

I have a Marshmallow device. It has custom built SW. 
[image]

I have seen the build.prop file. There I can perceive the Software version name comes from ro.custom.build.version

[image]

My question is - how can I get the "ro.custom.build.version" information programmatically in my application ?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697008/how-to-get-device-aosp-build-number-in-android-devices-programmatically

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/38569617/3421034

Comment: Thank you, @sasikumar .. it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. It is very simple - 
First, I created a function to read from SystemProperties.

```
public String getSystemProperty(String key) {
    String value = null;

    try {
        value = (String) Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties")
                .getMethod("get", String.class).invoke(null, key);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return value;
}
```

And then called the function with "ro.custom.build.version" as a key

```
getSystemProperty("ro.custom.build.version");
```

Special thanks to @sasikumar for giving me the hint

Answer (score 0):

You have to do as below :

```
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
String version = pInfo.versionName;
```

To get the Version code, Use as below :

```
int verCode = pInfo.versionCode;
```

Comment: This is not what he is looking for

Comment: Thanks. But your code get version from build.gradle of my application. I need the custom build version

Answer (score 0):

Check [android.os.Build.VERSION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html). You can use INCREMENTAL.